# Blocking only Flash and animated GIF images

Tags: firefox, browser, safari, blocking

What options are there for blocking Flash and animated GIF ads while keeping static image and text-only ads?

I'm interested in solutions for Firefox on Windows/Linux and Safari on OS X.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[FlashBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433)** will replace any Flash content on any website with a placeholder and play button (Firefox Addon).

**[SafariStand for Mac OS X](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html)** will block Flash content in Safari similar to FlashBlock for Firefox.

NirSoft's **[TurnFlash](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/tflash2.html)** allows you to easily disable and enable the Flash component in Internet Explorer.

*TurnFlash is freeware and "standalone", and it doesn't require installation.*

**[How to Stop GIF Image Animations from Playing in IE or Firefox](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2007/08/how-to-stop-gif-image-animations-from.html)**

*This also explains how to permanently block GIF animations in your browser:*

> In **Firefox** - Type about:config and
>   change the value of string
>   image.animation_mode from normal to
>   none.
>
> In **Internet Explorer** - Tools ->
>   Options -> Advanced. Uncheck the box in
>   Multimedia group that says "Play
>   animations in web pages"

Comment: i <3 FlashBlock.  it will block all flash by default, but you can whitelist sites, or just click the placeholder to play animations when you want.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively to blocking animated images you can simply disable animation. Open `about:config` in Firefox and set `image.animation_mode` to `once` or `none`

Comment: Note that this just prevents the animation (and is firefox only) and will just prevent the animation, while keeping the image/ad static.

Comment: +1 no installation.  thanks, i've wondered about this.

Answer (score 6):

[AdBlock plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865) can block all Flash animation, but as far as I know it can't distinguish between animated and static gifs.

The filter to block Flash would be `http://ad.uk.doubleclick.net/*.swf` (for example). You'll need to train AdBlock for all the different ad sites.

Comment: I done want to block all flash, just flash ads. Can adblock be configured to block *.swf from add sites?

Comment: @sal - sorry - just prefix the filter with the URL of the ad site. You'll have to train it though.

Comment: @sal, Adblock+ was meant to block only ads and not all flash, actually it's not that easy to make it block all flash things. As for training it, there are a few rather extensive subscriptions that will get you going.

Answer (score 1):

As regards the Safari/OS X part of the question, take a look at [ClickToFlash](http://rentzsch.github.com/clicktoflash/).

It's generic Flash blocker, so doesn't only block ads (but given the state of Flash on OS X that's not really a bad thing). It's got a whitelist, so you can add in sites where you're happy for Flash to load.

Comment: +1 Never heard of ClickToFlash but this looks pretty cool.